# Compiling PHP on Mac

Tags: php, macos

I'm trying to compile PHP on Mac but getting all these errors at the final step.

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/date/php_date.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/date/lib/astro.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ext/date/lib/dow.o'
...
```

I'm seeing *.lo files in those directories where it's expecting *.o.

Comment: Please tell us what commands you were using to build it....

Comment: Try compiling with gcc-llvm instead.

Comment: I'm just running "make".

Comment: @cleong How do I do that?

Comment: Append " CC=gcc" at the end of the configure command-line

Comment: Do you have to compile php from source. If not you could try using brew install PHP on your Mac.

Comment: Yes, I'm compiling from source.  I'm trying to create some custom PHP extensions.

Comment: Post the **full** output of **everything** after you've typed make. These errors may be the result of an earlier warning.

Comment: Four years later, and apparently this is still an issue as it happened to me today. For the benefit of anyone else hitting this problem, it seems to be related to using the '--enable-embed' flag, although that may not be the only cause.

Answer (score 0):

The First Thing you should do is install HomeBrew from http://brew.sh/. Then install php54 from Home Brew. This will instantly set it up for you.

Comment: I'm trying to create a PHP extension so I need to compile from source in order to build the extension.

Comment: @BerryBlue Are you sure those files are there? Also try the "cc=gcc"

Comment: you dont need compile php for compile a extension, any way homebrew compiles from sources, not is a binary distribution.

Comment: Can you enable ./configure options with homebrew installations of PHP such as --enable-debug and --enable-maintainer-zts?